# Updatebypk not calling afterSave in yii

Tags: php, yii

I have `updatebypk` in my controller to update a Model but i found that `updatebypk` not calling Yii `afterSave` function.It is the behaviour of `updatebypk`

```
Model::updateByPk($key,array('content'=>$content))// it is updating conten
```

Model.php

```
 protected function afterSave()
    {
      parent::afterSave();
       if(!$this->isNewRecord){
        $this->update_time = time();
       $this->update_by = Yii::app()->user->getId();
       $this->save(false);

      }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`updateByPk()` is using database query directly and not model's `save()` method and this is why it's not calling `afterSave()`. This is by design.